# How to find in PHP which part of the query "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..." succeeded?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have MySQL table that doesn't have AUTO_INCREMENT field. In PHP I run this simple query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ....");
```

I need to be able to detect if a new row was inserted into table or if an old row was updated ? Is it possible somehow ?

Comment: Well do you have a key in the database? (you were not specific)

Comment: I have an ID key in the table, but it's not AUTO_INCREMENT. And I also forgot to mention, that I don't want to run another query. I want to find solution just in PHP, no extra query.

Comment: try mysql_affected_rows(). It should return 1 for a simple insert, and 2 for a duplicate key update (I think, been a long time since I tried this).

Comment: @Marc B, I'd suggest to post that comment as an answer ;) And from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html - "*With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.*"

Comment: @Binary: you go ahead and post it. You took the time to look it up in the manual.

Comment: Yeah, I must have been blind that I've missed in the manual. Thanks, please post it as answer, I will try it out and accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_affected_rows()` returns 1 on an insert (because it inserted one row) and 2 on an update (because first it tried to insert, and then it updated, or something like that).

That is when you're just trying to add one row. You can have the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause on multi-row inserts too, and then you'll get the sum of 1's and 2's for all the rows.